# Byte-buddy delegating instance method to static method passing instance as a parameter

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I wonder if using byte-buddy i can crate method in class

```
public class Foo {

  //some fields and getters 

  public String newMethod() {
    return FooPrinter.createCustomToString(this);
  }
}
```

so that it will invoke

```
public class FooPrinter() {
  public static String createCustomToString(Foo foo) {
     return foo.getSomeField() + " custom string";
  }
}
```

I have tried

```
builder
    .defineMethod("newMethod", String.class, Ownership.MEMBER, Visibility.PUBLIC)
    .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(FooPrinter.class))
```

and adding `@This` to parameter in `FooPrinter` but i receive exception that non of methods in `FooPrinter` allows for delegatrion from `Foo.bar()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something else to your setup, this works just as expected:

```java
import net.bytebuddy.description.modifier.Ownership;
import net.bytebuddy.description.modifier.Visibility;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.This;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Foo instance = new ByteBuddy().subclass(Foo.class)
                .defineMethod("newMethod", String.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
                .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(FooPrinter.class))
                .make()
                .load(Foo.class.getClassLoader())
                .getLoaded()
                .getConstructor()
                .newInstance();

        Object result = instance.getClass().getMethod("newMethod").invoke(instance);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static class Foo {
        public String getSomeField() {
            return "someField";
        }
    }

    public static class FooPrinter {
        public static String createCustomToString(@This Foo foo) {
            return foo.getSomeField() + " custom string";
        }
    }
}
```

will print *someField custom string*.

Comment: Indeed it was my setup that was wrong, issue with class visibility as it was generated. Thanks